# Harry Potter fan fiction where he reads fairy tales and fantasy to learn magic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember reading it ages ago, it wasn’t finished at the time and was still being added to.

As much as I can remember was that Harry discovered his magic early and in a search for answers starts reading fairy tales and fantasy. This result in him experimenting with accidental magic and learning lots.

There was a strange bit early on where he reads Rapunzel and decides he wants really long hair.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/58193) to see if there is anything you can [edit] in? For example, you say you read this ages ago, roughly how long ago was that? Do you remember where you read this: fanfiction.net, A03?

Comment: Does he wind up rescuing a bunch of non-human children and bringing them to school with him?